# New IIS site - WebApp Error

Tags: iis

I setup IIS. I moved my folder with all the files to the IIS directory. Now when I go to http://localhost/thefolder
I get:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)]
   Luxand.FSDK.ActivateLibrary(String LicenseKey) +0
   FaceRecognition._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Project Details\Layne Projects\DotNet Project\FaceRecognition\FaceRecognition\Default.aspx.cs:60
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

- You don't have a license to run something included in the app (based on the ActivateLibrary(String LicenseKey) reference in the stack trace
- The app was compiled for a different platform than what you are installing it on.  (Compiled for 64 bit and you're installing it on 32 bit Windows/IIS)
- There's a corrupt file somewhere in the app.

What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows Vista

Comment: I'm using Vista Business 64 bit

Comment: If it's a 16-bit program it wont run on Windows 6.0+